# How do I see a modification of a commit in Git history?

Tags: git

As mentioned in the title, how should we view the modification of a certain commit in all history From the past starting with the first commit ?

Comment: What do you mean by "modification of a certain commit" ?

Comment: You can understand `appointed commit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all changed files from the last 24h in bash (or zsh):

```
git diff $(git rev-list -n1 --before="24 hours" --first-parent HEAD) HEAD --name-only
```

When you want to see what actually changed, leave out the `--name-only`

---

*Old answer*
I'm not sure what you mean by "all day history" but use `git show (commit-hash)` to view changes.
With `git log` you will get all commits including the hash

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. So all history from the beginning of the day or 24h into the past?

Comment: But what is the time period :) exactly 24h or just the beginning of the day?